# S3 connection through S3Hook

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, airflow

I want to connect to S3 using S3Hook instead of creating a connection in the airflow GUI or through CLI.

Currently while using S3Hook we try to fetch the existing connection that has been created through the UI. But I would like to create a connection programmatically using S3Hook in airflow.

```
hook = S3Hook(aws_conn_id="s3_connection")
```

Instead of just specifying the aws_conn_id, is it possible to add conn_type, host, login, password and other details inside S3Hook for it to create a connection ? When I tried doing the same, it is throwing the following error "unexpected keyword argument conn_type".

Comment: Can you explain the reason behind that request? Are you aware that you can set connection as environment variable? https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html#storing-a-connection-in-environment-variables

Comment: I've my aws_access_key and secret_access_key stored in a separate place, which I would like to retrieve on demand. Yes, I'm aware of the environment variable concept.

Comment: for that use case you will need to create a custom secret backend with your own logic https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/secrets/secrets-backend/index.html#roll-your-own-secrets-backend

Comment: Thanks for that. Could you please elaborate that a little ? Also, Can you please confirm if it's not possible to create a connection to S3 using S3Hook ?

Comment: If you strictly want to use `S3Hook` for that, the answer is no. You can use a combination of `aws_access_key` and `secret_access_key` stored as variables and `boto3`, but I don't know if that's your intention.